# How to create an irregular round shape in vapory

Tags: python, python-3.x, raytracing, moviepy, povray

I would like to render a large rock/boulder in vapory and currently I have a sphere with a stone texture. This looks ok but not very rock-like. Is there a way to create a more irregular or jagged round shape with vapory? Also if anyone can point me to any decent documentation of for the library I would appreciate that too.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have found, "Mesh approximator and surface displacement" might be a solution for you. Please check out [http://www.infradead.org/~wmp/macro_meshrelief.html](http://www.infradead.org/%7Ewmp/macro_meshrelief.html) for more information. The sample images look quite promising.